# Firebase query data only loads results for one of two collectionview custom cells

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionviewcell

So I have a UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally with two sections, each one being a different custom cell class that takes up the full view width and height. I am trying to load data from a Firebase query in ViewWillAppear into one of the cells/vertical screens.

For whatever reason, the Firebase values only will be assigned to my local variable in the second section. Nothing I do seems to allow me to populate that information in the first section. I have tested the data in the second custom cell and it populated exactly as I would have expected, which makes me think it isn't an issue with my query itself.

```
var fireData = [CustomStruct]() 
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     //attempted to make this as section == 1 and it does load data
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstCustomCell
      //custom cell variable is of the same type as this struct
       cell.setFireData = fireData

       return cell

    }
  //tested this cell just to see if it would return some of the data I was querying
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(secondCellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SecondCustomCell
    cell.setFireData = fireData
    return cell
  }

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) 

    ref.child("Data").child(selectedArea).queryOrderedByChild("userId")    
       .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snap) in

            if snap.exists() {

                    let fireInfo = CustomStruct(snap: snap) 
                    self.fireData.append(fireInfo)
                    self.fireData.sortInPlace({$0.timeElapsed < $1.timeElapsed})

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions or have any suggestions to fix this bug

Comment: Where are you defining selectedArea used in the Firebase observe section? Also why are you implementing dispatch_async in that section - you really don't want to update the UI until the variable data is valid so you may want to consider removing it. Last thing is that you are sorting and reloading your table after every child is loaded. You may want to wait until they are all loaded and then sort them and update the tableview. Depends on your use case.

Comment: what do you mean by defining the selected area? I have already added those values into the database from a separate view controller. After testing the query on a different area, I was able to load those values without a problem. Would you recommend moving the sorting of the struct and reloading the collectionview after completing the query so it only runs once? I really just need my collection view custom cells to have access to the data from my collection view controller

Comment: My confusion is that I temporarily passed the same struct to each custom cell to see if either would pick up the 10 database child values that I am looking for. When breakpointing I see that my second custom cell has the 10 values I am looking for, while the first stays empty. I am using a segmented control to navigate between each cell (they are full screen collectionviews) could that be part of the issue? The first custom cell is defaulted as the first and is the selected index

Comment: My question was more precisely: where are you defining the variable *selectedArea* which is used in the Firebase query. I want to make sure it's not going out of scope before using it, or that it's in scope when using it.  Another question:  fireData is an array of structures - could be 1, could be 100 in the array. In your cellForItemAtIndexPath, cell.setFireData is being set to the entire array. So therefore every cell is set to the entire array. Is that correct (maybe I am mis-reading it)

Comment: selectedArea is defined in the ViewWillAppear above the observer statement. Should I define that globally and then assign it a value within ViewWillAppear? Yes, I am assigning to my custom cell which is a collection view itself and is a data source and delegate. Therefore, I populate the cell's horizontal collectionview with that array of structures detail. The reason I am using this format is because I want both horizontal and vertical scrolling ability for my cell. Is there a better way to structure this format?